# How can I validate html 5 input type date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, date

I have a form where I have used new html 5 input type 'date'.How can I validate it with javascript?The value of input type data comes as mm-dd-yy together so, how can we find out that which part of date isn't entered by users?Either mm or dd or yy??We know theres default client side validation on input type date which might be done by browser but I want a code on js too which does that work.

********************* Question Updated **********************

**** I am trying this guys!Can you make some idea from it?Help need. ****

We all know input type='date' value will be in string type so, first from Js I took the value then as we know date format be like dd/mm/yy so..it will be eg :- 04/05/1995 now, I tried here to replace the '/' with '0' which will be a number so, in my guess it should be now 0400501995.After that I used a regular expression to test if that input type date has number or not.If user has entered all date then it will be all number and my test will be success and it will jump on last else statement.But the question is that its not working as what I suppose.Can we do that way guys?

On HTML I got

```
     Birthday: &nbsp;<input type="date" id='theDate' name="birthday"><br>
```

MY Js looks like below.

```
   var mydate = document.getElementById('theDate').value;
   var replacement = mydate.replace('/','0'); 
   var check = /^[0-9]+$/; 
   if(!check.test(mydate)) 
       {
          document.getElementById('theDate').style.borderColor = "red";
          document.getElementById('errorbdaysu').style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById('errorbdaysu').innerHTML = "Please fill up all your date";
       }  
 else {
        document.getElementById('theDate').style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById('errorbdaysu').style.display = "none";
      }
```

Comment: show us what have you tried ?

Comment: `value` property of `input type="date"` returns empty string if each of `mm/dd/yyyy` not input by user . What is expected range of dates user could enter ? Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: i'm afraid you can't get the value unless it's valid, so you can't be more specific in your error messages than "check date format". there are #shadow-root sub-element properties, but i don't think normal scripts can see those...

Comment: @Mritunjay i updated my question which shows now what i'm trying.looking forward for you all people help.

Answer (score 2):

> how can we find out that which part of date isn't entered by
>   users?Either mm or dd or yy??

`value` of `input type="date"` returns empty string if each of `mm/dd/yyyy` not set .

Valid attributes for `input type="date"` include `min` , `max` which could be utilized to specify a range of valid date selections.

See [`input type="date"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
  console.log(this.value)
  $("output").html(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- set valid range input date between `"2015-09-07"` - `"2015-09-30"` -->
<input id="date" type="date" min="2015-09-07" max="2015-09-30" />
<output for="date"></output>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer bro but can you help me with my new idea which isn't working I don't know if its possible or not.If its possible help me bro.

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg _"Can we do that way"_ Tried `var mydate = document.getElementById('theDate').value; console.log(mydate);`  ? Appear to return empty string or "yyyy-mm-dd" ; does not contain forward slash character `"/"` ? `js` not appear within event handler ? , would be called once ? What is expected result ?

Comment: `var bday = document.getElementById("theDate").value;
   if(bday == 0){ return fasle;} else{ return true;}` This code is doing my work I guess I won't have to go deep for now.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML date `<input>` date field is a regular input field that in some browsers has a special input box. Thus, you can validate it in JavaScript with the following code.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="dfield">
<button onClick="isCorrect()">Test</button>
```

JS:

```
function isCorrect() {
    // For form of mm-dd-yy
    var x = document.getElementById("dfield").value;
    if(isNaN(x.substring(0, 1)) || isNaN(x.substring(3, 4)) || isNaN(x.substring(6, 9))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is expected result of `x.substring(0,1)` ?

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of detecting missing dateparts to improve validation feedback, nor does it validate dates: `99-99-2000` would pass that test...

Comment: 'x.substring(0,1)' will return the first 2 digits of x.  I wrote this code to validate the form of the response.

Comment: @intboolstring `x` appear to be `document.getElementById("dfield")` ?

Comment: Yes, so `x.substring(0,1)` will be the first two characters in x.

Comment: @intboolstring What is `x` ?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add in `.value` to the end of that line.  You were right :).